# WooCommerce shipping address and billing filled, getting blank error after submit order on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to create Packets in my deliver system through SOAP API, on WooCommerce..

1. When is only billing address filled - everything is OK
2. When is billing and shipping address filled, all same - everything is OK
   But
3. When I change shipping address I get blank woocommerce-error alert
   Here is my PHP code:

   ```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', function($order_id) {
    global $wp, $wpdb, $woocommerce, $post;   

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT order_item_name FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = $order_id AND order_item_type = 'shipping'" );
    foreach ( $result as $shipping_method )
    {
      $method_shipping = $shipping_method->order_item_name;
    }

    if($method_shipping == 'Balíková přeprava Zásilkovna') {

      $client = new SoapClient("https://www.zasilkovna.cz/api/soap.wsdl"); 
      $apiPassword = "testesttestesttest";

      $formatted_billing_address = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
      $formatted_shipping_address = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();

      if($formatted_shipping_address == $formatted_billing_address) {
          $shipping_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
          $shipping_last_name  = $order->get_billing_last_name();
          $email               = $order->get_billing_email();  
          $phone               = $order->get_billing_phone();
          $payment_method      = $order->get_payment_method();
          $shipping_address_1  = $order->get_billing_address_1(); 
          $shipping_address_2  = $order->get_billing_address_2();    
          $shipping_city       = $order->get_billing_city();
          $shipping_state      = $order->get_billing_state();
          $shipping_postcode   = $order->get_billing_postcode();
          $shipping_country    = $order->get_billing_country();
      } elseif($formatted_shipping_address != $formatted_billing_address){
          $shipping_first_name = $order->get_shipping_first_name();
          $shipping_last_name  = $order->get_shipping_last_name();
          $email               = $order->get_shipping_email();  
          $phone               = $order->get_shipping_phone();
          $payment_method      = $order->get_payment_method();
          $shipping_address_1  = $order->get_shipping_address_1();     
          $shipping_address_2  = $order->get_shipping_address_2(); 
          $shipping_city       = $order->get_shipping_city();
          $shipping_state      = $order->get_shipping_state();
          $shipping_postcode   = $order->get_shipping_postcode();
          $shipping_country    = $order->get_shipping_country();
      }

      $order_total         = $order->get_total();

      $shipping_address = explode(" ", $shipping_address_1);
      $street = $shipping_address[0];
      $house_number = $shipping_address[1];
      if(strlen($house_number) == 0) {
        $house_number = $shipping_address_2;
      }            

      if($payment_method === 'cod') {
        $attributes = [
            'number' => $order_id,
            'name' => $shipping_first_name,
            'surname' => $shipping_last_name,
            'email' => $email,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'addressId' => 106,
            'cod' => $order_total,
            'value' => $order_total,
            'currency' => 'CZK',
            'weight' => 0.99,
            'street' => $street,
            'houseNumber' => $house_number,
            'city' => $shipping_city,
            'zip' =>  $shipping_postcode,
        ];

        } elseif($payment_method !== 'cod') {
          $attributes = [
            'number' => $order_id,
            'name' => $shipping_first_name,
            'surname' => $shipping_last_name,
            'email' => $email,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'addressId' => 106,
            'value' => $order_total,
            'currency' => 'CZK',
            'weight' => 0.99,
            'street' => $street,
            'houseNumber' => $house_number,
            'city' => $shipping_city,
            'zip' =>  $shipping_postcode,
        ];  
      }

        try {
          $client->createPacket($apiPassword, $attributes);                             
        }
        catch(SoapFault $e) {
          $order->add_order_note(print_r($e->detail)); // property detail contains error info
          $order->add_order_note(print_r($e->getMessage()));
          $order->add_order_note(print_r($client->__getLastRequest()));
          $order->add_order_note(print_r($client->__getLastResponse()));
        } 

      }
   ```

   }, 999);

Comment: There is no stock_status inside your code? Must be something else

Comment: Hello, after overthinking I think that error has no context with this because I did this more times and this error I have in debug log only one time and I didn't working with stock_status anywhere.. It's possible that there are some problem with different privileges to billing and shipping address or anything else? :)